# UITextfield not editable-iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have programatically created textfields that will not become editable when clicked. What am I doing wrong?

```
CGRect frame3 = CGRectMake(100, 730, 100, 30);
UITextField *textfield3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame3];
textfield3.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textfield3.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[self.view addSubview:textfield3];
```

Comment: Do you have a `UITextField` that is editable, and you don't want it to be? Or it's not editable, and you want it to be?

Comment: UITextField is *always* supposed to be editable, @Craig (I suppose it could be disabled by setting "`userInteractionEnabled`" to NO); but it's UITextView objects where editable is a property that can be set.

Comment: It's not editable and I would like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this, to start with:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

If you want to bring up the keyboard for the newly added text field, do this right after adding it as a subview to your parent view:

```
[textfield3 becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Is there anyway to not automatically open the keypad? When I add this it becomes editable but is open when I start the view and I can't go back to it once on another textfield

Comment: try doing "`[textfield3 resignFirstResponder];`" instead of "`becomeFirstResponder`".

Comment: It's strange only the ones I created on the xib are editable. I created this view controller with the text fields and am calling it in another view controller - Textfields *tf = [[Textfields alloc] init];  the ones programatically created are not editable