# Cannot make programmatically created UITextField editable (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I created a `UITextField` programatically, (I do not use storyboard) and added it as a `subview` to `ViewController` with this code:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *searchLocationBar;
@end
```

...

```
@synthesize searchLocationBar;
```

...

```
self.searchLocationBar = [[UITextField alloc] init];
self.searchLocationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 40.0f);
self.searchLocationBar.delegate = self;
self.searchLocationBar.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
self.searchLocationBar.placeholder = @"a temporary placeholder";
self.searchLocationBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.searchLocationBar.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[self.view addSubview:self.searchLocationBar];
```

However, I cannot enter any text - nothing happens, when I tap on a `textfield`. It's not overlapped by any other view.

I've  checked [UITextfield not editable-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478512/uitextfield-not-editable-iphone) but no effect

I'm newbie and totally sure I simply miss something - please advice.
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
One more thing: I have a Google Maps GMSMapView assigned to self.view as
    self.view = mapView_; as written in Google API documentation.
After some tests I found that with this declaration all controls work perfectly, but not textfields. I would prefer not to move a map view to any subview as I will need to rewrite lots of things.

Can someone please add any suggestions?

Comment: self.searchLocationBar.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25]; check it ?

Comment: Are you returning `NO` from `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` textfield delegate method?

Comment: comment this line self.searchLocationBar.delegate = self;
and check it its workking or not

Comment: @Alex Stalsky your code is working for me so might be other issue occur

Comment: It is working fine when I wrote this code. I can enter the text in it. Which xcode are you using - xcode4 or xcode5?

Comment: Forget about frames. Use autolayout. Otherwise yours app will be rejected in AppStore.

Comment: Why would an app be rejected from AppStore for not using auto layout?

Comment: xcode 5, ios 7 target

Comment: Thanks everybody!
I edited initial post as I missed a major detail. Sorry, still lack of knowlege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget add:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.searchLocationBar];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 5 your code should work.Better you check your Xcode version.May be the problem with your code with Xcode versions.You can try by following way.

```
UITextField *lastName = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 30)];
[self.view addSubview:lastName];

lastName.placeholder = @"Enter your last name here";   //for place holder
lastName.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;          //for text Alignment 
lastName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Thin" size:14.0]; // text font
lastName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;     //adjust the font size to fit width.

lastName.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];             //text color
lastName.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;        //keyboard type of ur choice
lastName.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;              //returnKey type for keyboard
lastName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;//for clear button on right side 

lastName.delegate = self;              //use this when ur using Delegate methods of UITextField
```

There are lot other attributes available but these are few which we use it frequently.if u wanna know about more attributes and how to use them refer to the following link.
You can also make property for UITextField.Either way should work fine in Xcode.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html